# Ubuntu External Monitor Only Shows Mouse Cursor

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, monitors

I am new to Ubuntu and installed 18.04.04 as a dual boot with Windows 10 on an Alienware Laptop. 
When I connect it to an LG 34UM88 34" Ultrawide Monitor, I only see a black screen with the mouse cursor.

I tried installing drivers with: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
but that didn't seem to fix it.

Any thoughts on what steps I might be able to take to configure this? When I contacted LG they said drivers should already be on Windows 10 -- but what about Ubuntu? It seems like the LG drivers might not be recognized, but I don't know how to make that happen.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and that did not work for me either.

The solution was uninstalling all NVidia drivers and use the open source driver for my GPU. Go to *Software & Updates* -> *Additional Drivers* --> *Using X.Org X Server (open source)*.

This option was blocked for me so I had to uninstall the NVidia drivers I had (probably the root cause of the issue). After uninstalling  my NVidia drivers and selecting the open source driver I was able to fix the issue. Probably reinstalling the NVidia drivers will also work now.

To find the nvidia drivers installed I used

```shell
sudo dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

and just deleted them with

```
sudo dpkg -P {nvidia-driver-xxx}
```

Works after rebooting`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without knowing your Alienware model number, but most likely it contains graphics hardware and/or CPU too new for full support by 18.04's 4.15 kernel, which was originally released in January 2018. The RTX™ 2080 Super I see from Google is used in recent Alienware models is more than a year newer than 18.04. Ubuntu 20.04 was released 6 months ago, and would have been a suitable choice of distro. You can probably make 18.04 drive your 3440x1440 display properly by upgrading to a backported 20.04 kernel and/or X Server and drivers, or more certainly by upgrading 18.04 to 20.04.